# (Wear OS) How to detect a long press of physical button on a smartwatch while the app is running in background?

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm a junior software developer and I need to develop an app for wear OS with the following key feature; to detect a long press of physical button on a smartwatch while the app is running in background. Is this even possible? If yes, I would truly appreciate for any links to samples and documentation.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible. The multifunctional buttons can be mapped to custom actions, but only when an application is running in the foreground. Otherwise they are controlled by the system (to e.g. act as a shortcut to Google Pay).

Even if it was possible, your app would only work on some devices since not all models have a multifunctional button. The only button that is guaranteed to exist on all devices is the power button, and this one you can definitely not get any events from in your app.

You've probably seen this already but I'm attaching it in case it's helpful to someone:

- Design guidelines plus recommended use cases and behavior can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/design/buttons)
- Implementation reference for the multifunctional buttons is [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/user-input/physical-buttons)

Comment: hmmm in my usecase detecting the press in foreground would be enough, but i think it is not working. sorry - no help for the original question from me